# Protect Apache server

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess

My server is attacked like this

```
188.165.198.65 ./../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00 HTTP/1.1" 200 28114 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1"
```

How can I defend it with .htaccess file?

Comment: You're probably better off asking this over at http://serverfault.com

Comment: If this is your server, why don't you use main Apache configuration files to prevent this from happening? This attack will never succeed on a properly configured Apache. .htaccess is intended to be used by users, not by server administrators.

Answer (score 2):

You are being scanned for directory traversal vulnerabilities.  It is very likely that these scans will return nothing,  but it could also be the precursor to a  compromise.

Without a doubt the best method to defend against this attack is using a **Web Application Firewall**  like [Mod_Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) which I know for a fact has a rule set which looks for "..\..\" in **all** http requests and drops the request before it hits your application.

Father more mod_security provides logs which greatly aids law enforcement in the case of a successful comprise.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to prevent this attack from succeeding is [the recommendations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles) from [Apache security tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/security_tips.html). They use Directory directive for that. Unfortunately that directive can't be used from .htaccess, so I propose using [Files directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#files) to protect your most sensitive files.